# How to measure data usage on Android Xamarin app?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

What would be best way to measure data usage in Android Xamarin app in Visual Studio?

I would like to know, how much data was transferred for each called request.
I was looking in Xamarin Profiler but there isn't any info about data usage.

Thanks.

Comment: What methods are you using to make your requests? Usually you can check the length of the web request and the length of the web response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach that you could use is via Android Device Monitor to watch network traffic

[image]

[image]

Alternatively you could wrap your request if you are using `HttpClient` in a custom handler and log the size of the request payload:

```
public class RequestLoggerHandler : HttpClientHandler
{

#if DEBUG
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        var headers = request.Headers;
        var responseString = string.Empty;
        var requestString = string.Empty;
        var outputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        const string LINE_ENDING = "===================================================================================================";
        const string SECTION_ENDING = "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";

        try
        {
            if (request.Content != null) requestString = await request.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();
            response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            responseString = await response.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();

            outputStringBuilder.AppendLine(LINE_ENDING);

            // Headers
            outputStringBuilder.AppendLine("REQUEST HEADERS:");
            foreach (var header in headers)
                outputStringBuilder.AppendLine($"HEADER: {header.Key}: {header.Value?.ToList()?.FirstOrDefault()}");
            outputStringBuilder.AppendLine(SECTION_ENDING);

            // Parameters
            outputStringBuilder.AppendLine("REQUEST PARAMS:");
            outputStringBuilder.AppendLine(requestString);
            outputStringBuilder.AppendLine(SECTION_ENDING);

            // Response
            outputStringBuilder.AppendLine("RESPONSE:");
            outputStringBuilder.AppendLine(responseString);
            outputStringBuilder.AppendLine(SECTION_ENDING);

            return response;
        }
        finally
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            var totalSize = 0L;

            if (response != null)
            {
                var bodylength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
                var headerlength = response.Headers.ToString().Length;
                totalSize = bodylength.GetValueOrDefault() + headerlength;
            }

            outputStringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("REQUEST [{0}:{1}] Time:{2}| Size:{3}| HTTP-CODE:{4}",
                request.Method.ToString(),
                request.RequestUri,
                stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("ss\\.fff"),
                totalSize.ToPrettyByteSize(),
                response?.StatusCode.ToString() ?? "No Internet Connectivity"));

            outputStringBuilder.AppendLine(LINE_ENDING);

            Debug.WriteLine("\n" + outputStringBuilder);
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Then in your output window using [VSColorOutput extension](http://mike-ward.net/vscoloroutput/) it produces a nice readable report of your request/response, including time and size. You can of cause simplify this code if all you are after is just the request/response size.

[image]